# HTMX inside a bootstrap-table

Tags: bootstrap-table, htmx

I am trying to use [bootstrap-table](https://bootstrap-table.com/) with HTMX.

I have a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/otLnrsmx/) with a working bootstrap-table, but the hx-confirm/hx-delete action does not work.
If you remove the `data-toggle="table` from the `table` element you can see, that the hx-confirm/hx-delete works as expected.

Any help to get HTMX inside a bootstrap-table working will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I got the hint in the right direction on Twitter, so I want to share the solution I came up with.

Here is a new [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eL6x4yqc/) with the solution.
I added the following script section at the end of the page after I added the id "dataTable" to the table element.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {     
        htmx.process(htmx.find("#dataTable"));
    });
</script>
```

This is already documented [in the 3rd Party Javascript section](https://htmx.org/docs/#3rd-party) and here the [documentation of the htmx.process method](https://htmx.org/api/#process)